# Suppressing The Command Window Opening When Using Start-Process

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to find a way to get PowerShell not to spawn a command window when running an executable using `Start-Process`.

If I call the executable directly within the script (e.g. `.\program.exe`) then the program runs (with its arguments) and the output is returned to the PowerShell window.

If I use `Start-Process` the program spawns a command window where the program runs and returns it's output.

If I try and use the `-NoNewWindow` switch of `Start-Process` the script then errors out saying it can't find the exe file.

I would prefer to use `Start-Process` to have access to the `-Wait` switch, as the programs and configurations the script makes can take some time individually to finish, and I don't want later commands starting up.

This code runs the executable in a separate command window:

```
Start-Process DeploymentServer.UI.CommandLine.exe -ArgumentList "download --autoDownloadOn --autoDownloadStartTime $StartTime --autoDownloadEndTime $EndTime" -Wait
```

This code runs the exe within the PowerShell console:

```
.\DeploymentServer.UI.CommandLine.exe download --autoDownloadOn --autoDownloadStartTime $StartTime --autoDownloadEndTime $EndTime
```

If I add the -NoNewWindow to the Start-Process code

```
Start-Process DeploymentServer.UI.CommandLine.exe -ArgumentList "download --autoDownloadOn --autoDownloadStartTime $StartTime --autoDownloadEndTime $EndTime" -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

I get the following error:

```
Start-Process : This command cannot be executed due to the error: The system
cannot find the file specifie
At C:\Temp\SOLUS3Installv1.3.ps1:398 char:22
+         Start-Process <<<<  DeploymentServer.UI.CommandLine.exe -ArgumentList "download --autoDownloadStartTime $StartTime --autoDownloadEndTime $EndTime" -Wait -NoNewWindow
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Comment: You might be able to `(Start-Process .\program.exe -NoNewWindow -PassThru).WaitForExit()`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should prefix the executable name with the current directory when you use the `-NoNewWindow` switch:

```
Start-Process .\DeploymentServer.UI.CommandLine.exe -ArgumentList "download --autoDownloadOn --autoDownloadStartTime $StartTime --autoDownloadEndTime $EndTime" -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

**Background information:**

The first thing `Start-Process` tries to do is to resolve the value of the `-FilePath` parameter by PowerShell rules. If it succeeds, it replaces the value value passed with the full path to the command. If not, it leaves the value untouched.

In the Windows API there are two ways to start a new process: `CreateProcess` and `ShellExecute`. `ShellExecute` is the default, but if you use a cmdlet parameter that requires `CreateProcess` (for example, `-NoNewWindow`), then `CreateProcess` will be used. The difference between them, which matters for this question, is that when looking for a command to execute, `CreateProcess` uses the current process' working directory, while `ShellExecute` uses the specified working directory (which `Start-Process` by default passes based on the current filesystem-provider location, unless explicitly specified via `-WorkingDirectory`).

```
PS Test:\> 1..3 |
>> ForEach-Object {
>>     New-Item -Path $_ -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
>>     Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
>>         static class Test {
>>             static void Main(){
>>                 System.Console.WriteLine($_);
>>                 System.Console.ReadKey(true);
>>             }
>>         }
>> "@ -OutputAssembly $_\Test.exe
>> }
PS Test:\> [IO.Directory]::SetCurrentDirectory((Convert-Path 2))
PS Test:\> Set-Location 1
PS Test:\1> Start-Process -FilePath Test   -WorkingDirectory ..\3 -Wait              # Use ShellExecute. Print 3 in new windows.
PS Test:\1> Start-Process -FilePath .\Test -WorkingDirectory ..\3 -Wait              # Use ShellExecute. Print 1 in new windows.
PS Test:\1> Start-Process -FilePath Test   -WorkingDirectory ..\3 -Wait -NoNewWindow # Use CreateProcess.
2
PS Test:\1> Start-Process -FilePath .\Test -WorkingDirectory ..\3 -Wait -NoNewWindow # Use CreateProcess.
1
```

PowerShell does not update the current process' working directory when you change the current location for the `FileSystem` provider, so the directories can differ.

When you type:

```
Start-Process DeploymentServer.UI.CommandLine.exe -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

`Start-Process` cannot resolve `DeploymentServer.UI.CommandLine.exe` by PowerShell rules, since it does not look in the current `FileSystem` location by default. And it uses `CreateProcess`, since you specify `-NoNewWindow` switch. So, it ends up looking for `DeploymentServer.UI.CommandLine.exe` in the current process' working directory, which does not contains this file and thus causes an error.

Comment: Excellent background info. To encourage good practices, it may be worth recommending to always invoke an executable in the current directory prefixed with `.\ `, even in cases where you don't strictly need it. Doing so unambiguously expresses the intent and prevents accidental execution of a different executable. (Comment reposted due to formatting problems.)

Comment: Just an additional tip (with help from @PetSerAl): To make the current process use the same working dir. as PS, run `[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = (Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath`. (A more verbose equivalent is `[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentFileSystemLocation.ProviderPath`.